# Can't read and echo back unicode input in C

Tags: c, unicode, wchar-t, wchar

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    wchar_t wc[80];
    wscanf(L"%ls", &wc);
    wprintf(L"%ls", wc);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: that's what i get as a result]

My terminal supports Unicode, compiled using gcc 8.2.1 on Linux.

Comment: You haven't told your C library to use the current locale, so it uses the default C/POSIX one instead.

Comment: so how do i do that?

Comment: you didn't have a new line in the printf

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fixed version of your program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t  ws[80];

    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, ""))
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: The C library does not support your current locale.\n");
    if (fwide(stdin, 1) < 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: The C library does not support wide standard input for your current locale.\n");
    if (fwide(stdout, 1) < 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: The C library does not support wide standard output for your current locale.\n");

    if (wscanf(L"%79ls", ws) < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    wprintf(L"%ls\n", ws);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The [`setlocale()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html) call tells the C library to use the currently configured locale.  If you don't do this, the C library uses its default locale (the C/POSIX one), which typically uses the ASCII character set (and not UTF-8).

The [`fwide(stdin, 1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwide.3.html) and `fwide(stdout, 1)` calls tell the C library you will use wide input functions with standard input, and wide output functions with standard output.  They will return -1 if the C library does not support it for the current locale; I believe that currently happens with UTF-8 based locales in Windows, because Microsoft wants programmers to use their proprietary extensions for this instead.

The `fwide()` calls are not required, because the C library will guess based on the first function you use for each stream.  I do recommend using them explicitly, so that the user knows if there is something iffy/wrong/unsupported about their current configuration or C library support.  It is just a couple of added lines, after all.

When scanning strings, you should always include the maximum allowed length in the pattern (immediately following the `%`).  Because C strings have a terminating nul character (`'\0'` for narrow strings, and `L'\0'` for wide strings), the buffer must be at least one longer.  Because `ws` is an array of 80 wide characters, `wscanf()` can scan a string of up to 79 characters into it.

All the scanning functions (`scanf()`, `wscanf()`, `fscanf()`, `fwscanf()` and so on) return the number of successful conversions, or EOF/WEOF. For example, if the user runs `true | ./thisprogram`, there is no input in standard input, and the `wscanf()` call would return WEOF.  Except for a couple of rare exceptions (using suppressed conversions to consume/skip data, or conversions using `%n`), you will want to check the return value.  If you do not check the return value in the above example (`true | ./thisprogram`), you end up printing an unintialized buffer of wide characters.  Which is not good; it can either print nothing, print garbage, or crash the program: it is Undefined Behaviour.

(It is also important to remember that if a conversion fails, the failed part remains in the input; it is not consumed or thrown away. It just sits there, unless you consume it.)

Certain shells add a `%` character at the end of the final output line if that line does not end with a newline.  Other shells put their own prompt immediately after that.  That is not an error, it just looks odd.  So, it is a good idea to always add a newline at the end of your outputs.

Standard output is also line-buffered by default.  In the above program, for example, using `wprintf(L"foo")` does *not* mean that the wide string `foo` is output; it is usually just buffered by the standard C library, and output some time later.  You can tell the standard library to output everything in its buffer for a specific stream, for example standard output, by using `fflush(stdout);`.  This applies to both normal/narrow and wide streams.  The C library will flush the buffers automatically when the program exits, however.